# How to calculate the side of square with the given two parallel lines?

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a square. I would like to calculate the side $x$. I have attempted different times, tried to add lines in $CE$, $AF$ but still cannot figure out how to solve it. Please give me some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: In the faint lines there is a $2 \times 2$ square.  What is the shape and size of the triangle with a vertex at $A$?

Comment: Hint: Try to calculate the *diagonal* of the square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edge from $A$ to $C$ is a diagonal of the square, and therefore must be $x\sqrt{2}$. So it is sufficient to find the length of the diagonal.

The diagonal is a line segment between $A$ and $C$. We can extend the two lines of length 2 and 3 to a rectangle, adding two additional sides. (There are faint lines where you tried this in the diagram!)

Then we can see that $\overline{AC}$ is the hypotenuse of a triangle with side lengths 11+3 = 14 and 2. So by the Pythagorean theorem, its length is $\sqrt{14^2+2^2} = 10\sqrt{2}$. So we know $x = 10$.